# Differentiate the Function: $y=2x \log_{10}\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=2x\log_{10}\sqrt{x}$

Solve using: Product Rule $\left(f(x)\cdot g(x)\right)'= f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}g(x)+g(x)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

and $\frac{d}{dx}(\log_ax)= \frac{1}{x\ \ln\ a}$

$(2x)\cdot [\log_{10}\sqrt{x}]'+(\log_{10}\sqrt{x})\cdot [2x]'$

$y'=2x\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\ln 10}+\log_{10}\sqrt{x}\cdot 2$

Answer in book is $y'= \frac{1}{\ln10}+\log_{10}x$

Answer (score 3):

Your derivative of $\log_{10} \sqrt{x}$ is incorrect. I recommend having another go and posting your working here for correction if you get the same thing.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/member.php?u=48520) you, @notnek?

Comment: Yes it is. I don't really like the posting solutions approach here so I probably won't post much. I'll stick to TSR.

Comment: @KhallilBenyattou, are you on TSR?! I'm Zacken there! :-)

Comment: Yep, I am @ZainPatel! My first name is my username. Haven't been active in a while but I'm still a member.

Comment: It's nice to see you here, @notnek. I'm not sure why, but I seem to have gravitated to here. I guess it's just that this site is a lot more active and the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) is easier to navigate.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You'll need to use the product rule with $2x$ and the logarithmic function.

Then, whilst applying the product rule, you use the chain rule on the logarithmic function.

Notice: differentiating $\log_a f(x)$ gives you (this is where you made your mistake) $$(\log_a f(x))' = \frac{f'(x)}{\ln a \cdot f(x)}$$

Use that with $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. In fact, you should get $$\bbox[border: solid blue 1px, 10px]{(\log_{10} \sqrt{x})' = \frac{1}{2x \ln 10}}$$

---

**Full solution:**

Hence, using the product rule we have the derivative as $$2x \cdot \frac{1}{2x \ln 10} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2x \ln 10} = \frac{1}{\ln 10} + \frac{1}{x \ln 10}$$

Comment: Yeah I just made the change. Still do not understand how they arrived at this answer.

Comment: @Cetshwayo, edited my answer.

Comment: I am still confused  if $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ wouldn't it's derivative be  $\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: It's derivative would be $$1/2 \cdot x^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Thus, your example (rule in blue box) is wrong then?

Comment: @Cetshwayo, why? What do you get?

Comment: How do I cancel it out? If I use this method of solving? I have $2x\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}ln10}+ log_{10}\sqrt{x}(2)$

Comment: That's not correct, you have $$2x \cdot \frac{1}{2x \ln 10}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26131/discussion-between-zain-patel-and-cetshwayo).

Comment: Anyways. So, since, we have f'(x) as that, then $f'(x)/f(x) = 1/2 * x^(-1/2) * x(-1/2) = 1/2 * x^(-1) = 1/(2x).$ Now just multiply that by $1/(ln a)$ to get $1/(2x ln 10).$

Answer (score 1):

$$\log\sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2}\log_{10} x= \frac{\ln x}{2\ln 10}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln x= \frac{1}{x}$$

using chain rule,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(2x\log\sqrt{x}\right)= 2x \frac{dx}{dx}\frac{\ln x}{2\ln 10} + \frac{\ln x}{2\ln 10}\frac{d}{dx} 2x $$

$$=\frac{2x}{2x\ln 10} + \frac{2\ln x}{2\ln 10} $$

$$ =\frac{1}{\ln 10}+ \log_{10} x$$

Note the change of base: $$\log_{10}x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 10} $$

Comment: There's not very much to finish off, is there? ;-)

Comment: This has now been edited. You need to relax man!

Comment: Whaaat? I was joking. You had "can you finish it off?" and I made a casual, joking remark about how you'd written almost everything already. I wasn't the downvoter, by the way.

Comment: Sry Zain, I thought you downvoted me there. I do get the joke by the way!

Comment: I thought that was an unfair downvote, I'll upvote to negate it. :-)

Comment: @ZainPatel, sometimes its hard to judge how far you should go with the solution. I suppose it depends on the OP and how much they're willing to have a crack at it. Thanks man-you're my maths buddy!

Comment: Haha, yay! You might wanna remove the "Hint" at the top of your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\frac{d}{dx}(\log_{a}(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(\log_{a}(e)(\log_{e}(x)))$$ Now, we have $$y=2x\log_{10}\sqrt{x}$$ $$\implies y=x\log_{10}(\sqrt{x})^2$$ $$\implies y=x\log_{10}(x)$$  $$\implies y=x\log_{e}(x)\times \log_{10}(e)$$ $$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\log_{10}(e)\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\log_{e}(x)\right)$$ $$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\log_{10}(e)\left(x\frac{1}{x}+(1)\log_{e}(x)\right)$$  $$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\log_{10}(e)+\log_{10}(e)\times \log_{e}(x)$$  $$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\log_{10}(e)+\log_{10}(x)$$  $$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\log_{10}(ex)$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that $$\log_{10} \sqrt{x} = \dfrac{1}{2} \log_{10} x$$

Then we have that $$ \begin{aligned} f(x) = \log_{10} (x) & \iff 10^{f(x)} = x \\ & \implies f(x) \log 10 = \log x \\ & \implies \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} f(x) \log 10 = \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \\ & \implies f'(x) \log 10 = \dfrac{1}{x} \\ & \implies f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x \log 10} \end{aligned} $$

Use the product rule and you should get your answer.

(Note that the above method for finding the derivative applies to any arbitrary base $0 < a \in \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: That's not right, it should be $2x \log 10$ in the denominator.

Comment: Why is that, @ZainPatel?

Comment: First equation. Factor of a half.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! :-)

Comment: I believe the problem specifies $f(x) = x~\log_{10}(x)$, I don't know if it was changed by edits or not.

Comment: It does indeed, @DanielV.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\log_{10}x$ as $\log x$.

$$y=2x\log\sqrt{x}=x\log x=\log x^x$$

$$10^y=x^x \implies y\ln10=x\ln x \implies y=\frac{x\ln x}{ \ln10}$$

Then

$$y'=\frac{1}{\ln10}\times(\ln x + 1)=\log x + \frac{1}{\ln 10}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[2x\log_{10}\sqrt{x}\right]$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left[2x\log_{10} x^{\frac12}\right]$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac22x\log_{10} x\right]$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\log_{10} x\right]$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x\log x}{\log 10}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{\log 10}\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\log x\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{\log 10}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\left[\log x\right]+(\log x)\frac{d}{dx}[x]\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\log 10}\left(\frac{x}{x}+\log x\right)$$
$$=\frac{1+\log x}{\log 10}$$
Which is equivalent to the books answer.